# optimize.leastsq ignore condition inside the function

Tags: python, scipy, least-squares

I try to use optimize.leastsq to find 2 parameters but I have condition 
so I add the condition to the function that calculates my model ,if the condition is broken a really big answer will be returned so the MSE will be huge.
but it's not working:

`data` is my set of real data and `p0` is a 2 parameters list:

```
p1, success = optimize.leastsq(errfunc, p0[:], args=(data))
errfunc = lambda p, y: (season1(p[0],p[1]) - y)**2

def season1(a, b, i=range(1, 150)):
    temp=[0.1875-0.1875*0.01, 0.1875+0.1875*0.01]
    S=0.999
    I=0.001
    R=0
    r=[0]
    for t in i:  
        S -= b*S*I             #Update S by the new t
        I = I+b*S*I-a*I    #Update I by the new t
        R += a*I  
        r.append(R)
    if R <= temp[1] and R >= temp[0]:
        print(R, a, b)
        return r
    return [1]*len(r)
```

Comment: *It's not working* is not an error-description to work with. Keep in mind, that you are at least ignoring the smoothness-assumption of those solvers.

Comment: How about using ``scipy.optimize.minimize`` with one of the bound methods (TNC) and as an objective function you could return the SSD?

Comment: Thanks, i try use scipy.optimize.minimize but i got an error :"Objective function must return a scalar" but i am returning a scalar

Comment: p1, success = optimize.minimize(errfunc, p0[:], args=(data),method='SLSQP',constraints=cons)
errfunc = lambda p,y: mean_squared_error(season1(p[0],p[1]) - y)  # Distance to the target function
mean_squared_error return a scalar so where is the problem